# Simon says game for android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-canvas

Recently I have been trying to get done a Simon says game for android, and is getting more difficult than expected.

Right now the game is almost done, the engine works fine, the game logic is doing well, etc... the problem comes when the sequence must be shown by itself in the display so the player can copy it.

The sounds are working fine but when sequence must be done nothing gets drawn until the method finishes.

It is important to say that a Pause between each move must be done, for this sake I have tried a lot of things with the same result in each of them:

- Thread.sleep(...);
- SystemClock.sleep(...);
- AsyncTask doing just some sleep and then rising a flag...
- View.invalidate();
- View.postInvalidate();

And so on...

The best result gets with SystemClock.sleep(...) the screen does not show anything but everything else works just fine.

Is also important to explain that I'm not using drawables or xml files to draw the buttons, instead of that I'm drawing the shapes with a Path and a Paint right on the Canvas and all of this inside a SurfaceView.

I'm putting here the methods that I think are not working fine, there is some more code in the project but it seems to be working and not messing up anything.

This is the surfaceView class with the most important methods for what we are doing:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

//Elementos del thread
public MySurfaceThread thread;
public boolean touched;
public boolean reproduciendo;
public boolean juega;
public boolean despierta;
public boolean llamaPausa;


//Colores
public int mediumOrchid = 0xBA55D3;
public int crimson = 0xDC143C;
public int gold = 0xFFD700;
public int cornFlowerBlue = 0x6495ED;
public int limeGreen = 0x32CD32;

public int darkOrchid = 0x9932CC;
public int fireBrick = 0xB22222;
public int goldenRod = 0xDAA520;
public int midNightBlue = 0x191970;
public int mediumSeaGreen = 0x3CB371;

public int[]colores = {mediumOrchid, crimson, gold, cornFlowerBlue, limeGreen};
public int[]tocados = {darkOrchid, fireBrick, goldenRod, midNightBlue, mediumSeaGreen};


//Coordenadas de pulsación
PointF click;

public int indice = 0;
public int repId;


private int correctas;
private Vector<Integer> secuencia = new Vector<Integer>();
private Random aleatorio;


//Sonido
SoundPool mp;
int idBell1;
int idBell2;
int idBell3;
int idBell4;


Activity padre;


public MySurfaceView(Context context, SoundPool mpObj, Random rnd) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    aleatorio = rnd;

    //Soundloop
    mp = mpObj;
    idBell1 = mp.load(context, R.raw.sy01, 1);
    idBell2 = mp.load(context, R.raw.sy02, 1);
    idBell3 = mp.load(context, R.raw.sy04, 1);
    idBell4 = mp.load(context, R.raw.sy06, 1);


}



@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread = new MySurfaceThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRun(true);
    thread.start();
    Log.e("surfaceCreated", "Creado");






}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    boolean retry = true;
    //Detenemos el hilo
    thread.setRun(false);
    while (retry){
        try{
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }

}


 @Override
public  void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if(reproduciendo){Log.e("onDraw", "Entro a onDraw desde repsec");}
    //Fondo negro
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    //Creamos el pinceles
    Paint pincel = new Paint();
    pincel.setAntiAlias(true);
    pincel.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    if (touched){//Activates when user is touching the screen
        int id = quePieza(click, canvas);
        //Log.e("onDraw", touched + " " + id);
        if(id != -1) colores[id] = tocados[id];
    }

    if(reproduciendo){//Activates when sequence must be shown, just changes colours in the  color array conveniently
        Log.e("onDraw", "repId = " + repId);
        if(repId != -1){colores[repId] = tocados[repId];}
        repId = -1;
        correctas++;
        Log.e("onDraw", "Correctas = " + correctas);
    }
    //Pintamos las piezas
    for(int i = 0; i < colores.length; i++){
        pincel.setColor(Color.rgb(Color.red(colores[i]), Color.green(colores[i]), Color.blue(colores[i])));
        pintarPiezas(i, canvas, pincel);//Paint each button according to an int code (0 to 4)
    }

    //Pintamos el texto
    pincel.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    dibujarTexto(canvas, pincel);

    //Reestablecemos colores originales
    resetColor();
    //Log.e("onDraw", "He terminado de pintar");



}
```

This one is the method in charge of showing the sequence in the display:

```
public void reproducirSecuencia(final Canvas canvas){
    reproduciendo = true;
    //TODO: HACER QUE ESTO FUNCIONE!!
    Log.e("reproducirSecuencia", "Entro a reproducir");

    int i = 0;

    while(i < secuencia.size()){

        Object o = secuencia.elementAt(i);
        int num = 0;
        if (o instanceof Integer) {num = (Integer) o;}


        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            i++;
            reproducirSonido(num);
            repId = num;
            onDraw(canvas);
            i++;



        //Log.e("reproducirSecuencia", "repId = " + repId);
        //Log.e("reproducirSecuencia", "Invoco a pintarPiezas");





        //SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        //try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
        //catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    reproduciendo = false;
}
```

And finally this is the main method that is playing in the game Thread:

```
public void Play(Canvas canvas){


    /*if(juega){
        int piezaTocada = quePieza(click, canvas);
        reproducirSonido(piezaTocada);
        juega = false;
    }
    onDraw(canvas);*/

    onDraw(canvas);

    if (secuencia.isEmpty()){//Creamos el primer movimiento
        crearMovimiento();
        reproducirSecuencia(canvas);
    }
    else{//Sigue el juego
        if(juega){//Esperamos a que haya una jugada
            int piezaTocada = quePieza(click, canvas);//Method to find which button was pressed
            //¿Coincide con lo que buscamos?
            if(piezaTocada != 0){//Que no se cuente el botón central en el modo classic
                reproducirSonido(piezaTocada);
                if(esCorrecto(piezaTocada, secuencia.elementAt(indice), canvas)){//Check if user's move was correct or not
                    //Aumentamos el indice
                    indice++;
                    juega = false;//Acabamos con la jugada
                    if(indice > secuencia.size() - 1){//Hemos hecho toda la secuencia, ponemos un nuevo elemento y reiniciamos
                        //SystemClock.sleep(3000);

                        indice = 0;
                        crearMovimiento();

                        int buc = 0;
                        reproducirSecuencia(canvas);
                    }

                }
                else{//No es correcto...
                    gameOver(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also putting in my Thread class since it seems to be getting blocked while playing the sequence:

```
public class MySurfaceThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder surface;
private MySurfaceView view;
private boolean run;
public boolean pausa;


//Metodo constructor
public MySurfaceThread(SurfaceHolder sh, MySurfaceView v){
    this.surface = sh;
    this.view = v;
}



public synchronized void pausar() {
    pausa = true;
}

public synchronized void reanudar() {
    pausa = false;
    notify();
}

public synchronized void detener() {
    run = false;
    if (pausa) reanudar();
}


public void setRun(boolean r){
    this.run = r;
}



public  void run(){





    //...
    //Creamos un canvas
    Canvas canvas;
    //Mientras run sea true pintamos
    while (run){


        canvas = null;
        try {

            canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);
            //Usamos syncro
            synchronized (surface){

                if(canvas != null){//Si el canvas existe pintamos
                    view.Play(canvas);

                }
                while (pausa) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (canvas != null){
                //Liberamos el canvas y el soundPool
                surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

}

This is it, I would apreciate answers as clear as possible since this is my first app and I have early one year coding and a few months trying with android.

Thanks a lot!

Luis.

Answer (score 1):

No no no. Don't sleep in your main thread, it will block your UI - which is exactly what you're experiencing. You should play one sound, then set a timer. Once the timer expires, play the next sound, set another timer and so on.

One easy way to set a timer is to use [`Handler.sendMessageAtTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageAtTime%28android.os.Message,%20long%29)

Comment: Can you explain a little more detailed how do you recommend to set this timer?